# Java- if else... if something is something or something?

Tags: java, if-statement, collision, operation

Okay, I'm making this new game in Java. This might be a simple question, but can anyone please help me with this?

So, if the "Guy" collides with the platforms, he can't move right (obviously).

This is what I got:

```
if(Guy.x + Guy.width == (platform2.x ^ platform3.x)) {} else{
                    goRight();
}
```

The "^" is supposed to be "or".
I have a void called goRight();

so it would be like "if Guy's x plus Guy's width is the same as platform2 or platform3's x then go right. I don't want to have to do this:

```
if(Guy.x + Guy.width == platform2.x || Guy.x + Guy.width == platform3.x)) {} else{
            goRight();
}
```

And plus, I have like 20 more platforms so it would be easier the first way if it's possible.
And I have to make the left collision detection too.

Comment: Try adding parentheses to group things.

Comment: The corret way to do it is by using the or operator, as you don't want to do it. If you have 20 platforms to check, then put them in a collection and use a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Platform is a class that has an x value, then I'd suggest putting put all of your platforms into a collection of some kind and iterating over it.  Inside a loop, do something like

```
for(Platform p: platforms){
     if(Guy.getX() + Guy.getWidth() == p.getX()){
        //whatever
     }else{
        goRight()
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of using loops, and I used it, but for some reason it didn't work. What is "null pointer exception?" (it said that on the console)

Comment: That means that one of your field values is null.  I also adjusted my answer a little, because Java doesn't do direct field access.  Does your NPE have a stack trace that might help?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to repeat the conditions.

One (better) solution would be to create a collection with your `x` variables and using the `.contains()` method on it. That would make your code a lot more readable.

Alternatively, put all your platforms in a collection, loop over it and check each value's `x` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need some more advanced structures to store information about your platforms. Consider having a `Set` of the x-coordinates of your platforms and performing the operation 'contains`

for example:

```
Set<Integer> xcoords = new HashSet<Integer>();
xcoords.add(platform2.x);
xcoords.add(platform3.x);

if (xcoords.contains(Guy.x + Guy.width)){
} else {
    goRight();
}
```

Comment: Is creating a `Set` for this *really* necessary?

Comment: well, it does have some advantages (e.g. speed), but those depend on how-often you can reuse the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way the language is designed... So it is useless to fight against it.

All you can do is use auxiliary variables to shorten the expressions. But you will always have to right something like `if(a == b || a == c)`.